# how to check if any site collection is associated with web application

Tags: powershell, site-collection, web-application

I have created Web Application with Powershell. I want to check if any site collection is associated with web application using powershell? How it can be checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `Get-SPSite -WebApplication http://sharepoint -Limit All` should do the trick.